# Vue mixin render HTML and append to $ref

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use a mixin to find a referenced Node and then append some HTML to it rendered using Vue, so I can pass data into it.

```js
const Tutorial = guide => ({
    mounted() {
        this.guide = guide;

        this.html = Vue.compile(`<p>Test</p>`).render;

        guide['add-location'].forEach(step => {
            this.$refs[step.ref].appendChild(this.html);
        })
    },
    data: function() {
        return {
            guide: null,
            html: null
        }
    }
});
export default Tutorial;
```

This is what I have at the moment, it gets the ref correctly, just can't append the HTML as I don't think i'm using `Vue.compile` correctly.

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: `Vue.compile(<p>Test</p>).render` is a function not `Node` so it cannot use with `appendChild`. May I ask you why you use `Vue.compile` what about set that html to variable and use `v-html`?

Comment: I want to be able to add the content of the `p` tag from the data for example and generate more HTML without using the dirty old `createElement` way

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, It's better if we can avoid mutate DOM directly. What about replace `ref` with `v-html`?

```js
const tutorial = guide => ({
  mounted() {
    guide['add-location'].forEach(step => {
      this[step.ref] += this.html;
    })
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      ...guide['add-location'].reduce((result, step) => {
        result[step.ref] = ''
        return result
      }, {}),
      html: `<p>Test</p>`
    }
  }
});

const Foo = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-html='foo'></div>
      <div v-html='bar'></div>
    </div>
  `,
  mixins: [tutorial({
    'add-location': [
      { ref: 'foo' },
      { ref: 'bar' }
    ]
  })]
}
```

Another idea is using wrapper component to wrap target or if your target is a component then you create a wrapper as mixin too.

Using with html property:

```html
<wrapper ref='foo'>
  <div>Foo</div>
</wrapper>
```

```js
const Wrapper = {
  props: ['html'],
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [this.$slots.default, h('div', {
      domProps: {
        innerHTML: this.html
      }
    })])
  }
}

...

this.$refs.foo.html = '<h1>Hello Foo</h1>'
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0vct68qL/)

Or using with custom appendChild method:

```js
const Wrapper = {
  data: () => ({
    children: []
  }),
  methods: {
    appendChild(child) {
      this.children.push(child)
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h('div', [
      this.$slots.default,
      ...this.children.map(child => h('div', {
        domProps: {
          innerHTML: child
        }
      }))
    ])
  }
}

...

this.$refs.foo.appendChild('<h1>Hello Foo</h1>')
this.$refs.foo.appendChild('<h1>Hello Bar</h1>')
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/e1b7ta9k/)

Or using with `Vue.compile` in case that html is not plain html:

```js
const Wrapper = {
  data: () => ({
    template: '',
    context: {}
  }),
  methods: {
    setChild(template, context) {
      this.template = template
      this.context = context
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    let res = Vue.compile(this.template)
    return h('div', [
      this.$slots.default,
      h({
        data: () => this.context,
        render: res.render,
        staticRenderFns: res.staticRenderFns
      })
    ])
  }
}

...

this.$refs.foo.setChild('<h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>', {
  name: 'Foo'
})
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qtzc6hbm/)

Comment: Had to put this on hold, but these are some great examples. I will look into it soon and let you know which one I went with. The wrapper one seems better for my use-case.